# Not able to update context after Axios POST request and I get a error in the rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I make a webshop application and after the user is submitting their cart I send a request to the backend. In the backend there is an order created based on that information and the created order is send back. When I get this order back from the backend I want to update the general context(state) with this order information.

```
// CartState.js
  const sendOrder = async (order, person) => {
    const body = JSON.stringify({ order, person });
    // CALL API
    try {
      const response = await API.post('/orders', body);
      const { data } = response;
      dispatch({ type: SEND_ORDER, payload: data });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

 case SEND_ORDER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        order: action.payload,
        items: state.items.map(item => {
          item.count = 0;
          return item;
        })
      };
```

But when I get a status 200 with the new order back and the right object (regarding to the console log I have made) the context is not updated.

```
{
payment_status: "not paid"
delivery_moment: "As soon as possible"
items: [{…}]
_id: "5e7e3c842c2a0236a42b09d2"
person: {name: "Dennis Klarenbeek", email: "dennis.klarenbeek@icloud.com", phone: "0622225086", street: "Glindhorst, 52", city: "EDE", …}
vendor: "5e7de28d6514432ed7a71787"
created: "2020-03-27T17:48:52.495Z"
order_id: 10034
__v: 0
}
```

In the rendering part of react he continuously say: Cannot destructure something is null. And null is the initialstate of order.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot destructure something is null. And null is the initialstate of order.`

I guess you set the initial value of `state` to be `null`?

I think you need to set the initial value of `state` to be `{}` (empty object), so that it can be processed by spread/destructure operator (the `...state`)

Comment: Hi, After I changed this, the new state is still not updated after de response comes in. Which will lead in a render error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. because there is nothing inside the object.

Comment: Hmm...empty object is not the same as undefined. i think it comes from somewhere else

Comment: The new component rendered before I got the answer back from the server. So when I included async / await into that function the rendering takes place when the state is already updated.

Answer (score 0):

In the function where I called the backend server there was no async/await or promised handle. So the new component rendered before the state was updated.
With the addition of async / await, the new component will render when the order state is updated!